# Get enviroment variable out of docker compose file in asp.net core in Azure web app

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a ASP.NET core application that gets it environment variable from a docker compose file. In Azure this doesn't work somehow.
I have an App service > web app > multi-container app

```
 <container>:
     container_name: <container_name>
     image: <image>
     environment:
       - DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING:Server=tcp:<location>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<db>User ID=<user>;Password='<password>';Encrypt=true;
     networks:
      - <network>
     build:
      context: .
```

And for the startup

```
 services.AddDbContext<<dbcontext>>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING")));
```

Note that it DOES work locally. What am I doing wrong?
So I need to read environment variable and use that to connect to the right database.
thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, you mean that the env var is not defined in your container or it doesn't have the right value?

Comment: Have you enabled debugging on container? What is there in value for environment variable DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING

Comment: Thanks guys it was an = instead of an : and the error was (among others) that the connectionstrings couldn't be zero

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake was

```
 environment:
       - DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING:Server=
```

instead of

```
 environment:
       - DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING=Server=
```

It was the : instead of an =

and I also changed the following but I'm not sure this HAD to be done.

```
services.AddDbContext<<dbcontext>>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING")));
```

is used

```
services.AddDbContext<<dbcontext>>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING"]));
```